# Saving raw ANSI escape codes in M-x shell, M-x eshell, or M-x term

Tags: shell, eshell, term

Each of `M-x shell`, `M-x eshell`, and `M-x term` in Emacs lets me save the buffer to a text file.  But the terminal colors are not saved.  How do I save the raw ANSI escape sequences too?

Comment: I'm afraid that the codes are removed before displaying the text, so there's no way to save them afterwards (maybe you can infer them from the faces, but that won't work all the time).

Comment: @wvxvw if that's the case, I don't think it would be easy to make this possible. `term` and others would require substantial rewrites to give them this capability.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10: it would be extra work to re-create the escape sequences afterwards, indeed, but there's a simpler option: save the program's output directly into a file before decoding the escape sequences.

Comment: Maybe `enriched-mode` could be used to save the colors? (not the original ANSI escape sequences though).

Comment: @Stefan yes it would work for non-interactive program (e.g. `ls --color=always > /some/path`) but not for interactive program (e.g. `mc`). I suppose another alternative is GUI screenshot.

Comment: @GerryLufwansa: I was thinking of saving the data received by Emacs rather than piping through something like `tee`: that should work in all cases.

Comment: @Stefan yes that'd be great. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like the 100% guaranteed untested code below:

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(defun sm-save-proc-output ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (get-buffer-create "*SM-Saved-Proc-Output*"))
        (proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (add-function :before (process-filter proc)
      (lambda (_proc string)
        (with-current-buffer buf
          (save-excursion
            (goto-char (point-max))
            (insert string)))))))
```

It won't let you save the *current* content, but instead, sets up the buffer `*SM-Saved-Proc-Output*` to receive a copy of all the output of the process running in the current buffer.  You can then later save that buffer's content with `M-x write-region` or `M-x write-file`.

Comment: `get-buffer-process` requires an argument so I changed it to `get-buffer-process "*shell*"` (testing it with `M-x shell` first). There's another error (or warning?) `Symbol's value as variable is void: v` and the `*SM-Saved-Proc-Output*` buffer is still empty. I'm stumped at this point.

Comment: I fixed the call to `get-buffer-process` and the other problem is probably because your file probably doesn't have the `lexical-binding` set (see the comment I added as first line).